# Object(...) is not a function (react + firebase)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Below is the auth function that I will call in my Join.js

```
import { firebaseAuth } from './firebase'

export function auth (email, pw) {
  return firebaseAuth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw)
}
```

So my return statement got error, it said Object(...) is not a function. So at my Join.js, I console.log and I got undefined for this.email.value

```
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(`${this.email.value}`);
    auth(this.email.value, this.pw.value)
        .catch(e => this.setState(setErrorMsg(e)))

}
```

Below is the form that I accept from user

```
<Form size='large' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <Form.Group>
    <label  >Username</label>
    <Input className="Name" ref={(username) => this.username = username} />
  </Form.Group>
  <Form.Group>
    <label>Password</label>
    <Input type="password" className="PW" ref={(pw) => this.pw = pw} />
  </Form.Group>
  <Form.Group>
    <label>Confirm Password</label>
    <Input type="password" className="JoinConfirmPW" />
  </Form.Group>
  <Form.Group>
    <label>Email Address</label>
    <Input className="JoinEmail" ref={(email) => this.email = email}/>
  </Form.Group>
  <Form.Group>
    <label>Gender</label>
    <Form.Select className="JoinGender" options={options} placeholder='Gender' ref={(gender) => this.gender = gender} />
    </Form.Group>
    <Button color='teal' className="submit">Sign Up</Button>
  </Form>
```

I don't know why I got undefined. Can anyone help?

Comment: So I solve this error by copying the entire firebase.js from react-firebase (Github). I'm not sure why I got this error but at least I am able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `firebaseAuth()` is undefined.

your firebase.js file should be like,

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';

...

const db = firebase.database();
const firebaseAuth = firebase.auth();

export {
  db,
  firebaseAuth,
};
```

and the auth is used like,

```
 firebaseAuth.doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwordOne)
  .then(authUser => {

    // Create a user in your own accessible Firebase Database too
    db.doCreateUser(authUser.user.uid, username, email)
      .then(() => {
        this.setState(() => ({ ...INITIAL_STATE }));
        history.push(routes.HOME);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState(byPropKey('error', error));
      });

  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.setState(byPropKey('error', error));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 mistakes in your code. Firstly don't store the values of input fields in local variables. Instead, use state and set the value using the `this.setState()` method. I know this might sound silly and shouldn't make much of a difference but it eliminates the possibility of any scope-related issues.

Secondly the firebase call you are making is invalid. It should be something like `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password);`

provided you have the values in the state variables. Else use the appropriate variables as parameters to pass the email and password. Hope it works because it does for me.